# Can I add multiple data sources without linking the tables in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have multiple tables i want to display in the dashboard, but tableau force me to link them. Is is possible to add the tables without linking them?

Comment: Please provide an example/code for your question

Answer (score 13):

**Yes.**

If, from a standard Tableau sheet, you click the Data menu and "New Data Source", you can add another unrelated data source to any already open. This can later be blended to existing tables but you don't *have* to blend it and it can stay independent from them.

You are only obliged to join tables when you add them at the same time in the new data source screen as the point of that screen is to allow you to define joins between multiple data sources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!